# REST in ASP.NET Core: validate a missing value type field on a PUT object

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core

For example you have a class that you intend to expose via your public RESTful API:

```
public class MyExposedType
{
    [Required]
    public bool MyExposedValueType { get; set; }
}
```

Consider a `PUT` operation with the body `{}`. In this situation I would expect the API to return a `BadRequest`, but instead the object is accepted.

Since `MyExposedValueType` is a value type, it cannot be null and defaults to false. However, typically for a `PUT` operation, you must provide values for all the fields in the object to replace.

I know I could expose a DTO with a `[Required]` nullable bool on it. Is there a better way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the exported model is protocol-agnostic. In some cases it can be explicitly stated, that the default values can be omitted in the request. For the `bool` the default value is `false`, so it may be even expected that in case of `false` there is nothing in the request.

To specifically require the value in the request, you need to either change the default value to `null` (by changing the property to nullable), or to adjust the model specifically for some protocol. For example, newtonsoft.json has a `JsonRequiredAttribute` (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonRequiredAttribute.htm). But it will only work in case of JSON deserialization, and only if you use newtonsoft.json.

Answer (score 0):

Making the type nullable as you suggest should be fine? It's only a DTO after all - not a domain object which is more likely to enforce 'proper' types, if appropriate.

Comment: Yeah I agree, it would work. I'm hoping there is a simpler way to achieve it rather than adding extra types, mapping etc.